# Can somebody explain me chmod permissions like I'm five?

Tags: apache, file-permissions, directory-structure

I am unsure what to set my file permissions to.

I understand the concept, and how to do it, but I do not know what kind of consequences each setting has.

the options are **read, write, execute**, and there are three different categories where I can check each option: **owner, group, public**.

the default setting for my folders seems to be `drwxr-xr-x` or `755`. I assume `d` stands for directory?

For files the standard usually is `-rw-r--r--` or `644`.

While I am not terribly interested in learning exactly how the encoding of permissions works, I would rather like to know what each option does, and how each group is separate.

Who is the owner, who is a group, who is public?
Exactly what kind of permissions does read, write, and execute give to each of them (owner, group, public)?

So there would be 9 options, I assume that there are 9 use cases. Like "give the `public` the permission to `write` if you want to give visitors of your website the ability to upload files to this folder."

I have also realized, that not giving `read` permission to `public` results in 403 when trying to access a file.

So what are the 9 different scenarios, what are consequences for giving or removing a certain permission, on both files and folders?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [unix.se]

Comment: Have you tried `man chmod`? Wikipedia also has a [good article on modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modes_(Unix\)).

Comment: Thanks Amadan, this article somewhat helpful... I am looking for a very basic explaination however... who exactly is the owner? What exactly is a group? What consequences has each setting under the consideration of a php webapp?

Answer (score 2):

Basically:

Category:

- **owner:** *Whoever created the file (Also, when a file accesses another file from within the same domain, that file is considered an **owner** of the file)*
- **group:** *People within your defined file group.  For how to define a group, you can visit this question: https://superuser.com/questions/341740/how-to-specify-group-with-chmod*
- **everyone:** *People who visit your website*

Privilege:

- **read:** *Ability to see the file*
- **write:** *Ability to change the file*
- **execute:** *Ability to delete the file*

Comment: How do I define a group? And in what category do php scripts fall? For example can I set permissions on a file, so that my php script can read the contents, but visitors to my website have no access to it?

Comment: The updated answer should answer all of those questions.

Answer (score 1):

The owner is the user who created the file, and the group is the primary group of the owner, unless changed by `chown` and `chgrp`. The file owner and group are the two names that can be seen when you say `ls -l`. On many (but not all) systems, each user's primary group is named by the user; so user `amadan` would belong to a group `amadan`, among any other secondary groups he may or may not be a member of. Any file he creates would look like this:

```
-rw-r--r--  3 amadan  amadan    102 Feb 14 18:34 test
```

Very often, Apache web server will run as user `www-data`, also having the primary group `www-data`. If you execute `chgrp www-data test` and `chmod 664 test`, you get:

```
-rw-rw-r--  3 amadan  www-data  102 Feb 14 18:34 test
```

This will mean the following:

- The user `amadan` can read and write the file.
- Anyone in the group `www-data` (whether primary group, or one of the secondary groups), which in this case means Apache web server, will also be able to read and write the file.
- Anyone who is not `amadan` and not in the `www-data` group will only be able to read the file.

You can find out which groups you belong by `groups amadan` (well, obviously, your own user name instead :p). You can see what username and group your Apache runs under by checking `User` and `Group` directives in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` or similar file (varies by OS and Apache version).